# Are there well-known "profiles" of the C standard?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I write C code that makes certain assumptions about the implementation, such as:

- `char` is 8 bits.
- signed integral types are two's complement.
- `>>` on signed integers sign-extends.
- integer division rounds negative quotients towards zero.
- `double` is IEEE-754 doubles and can be type-punned to and from `uint64_t` with the expected result.
- comparisons involving NaN always evaluate to false.
- a null pointer is all zero bits.
- all data pointers have the same representation, and can be converted to `size_t` and back again without information loss.
- pointer arithmetic on `char*` is the same as ordinary arithmetic on `size_t`.
- functions pointers can be cast to `void*` and back again without information loss.

Now, all of these are things that the C standard doesn't guarantee, so strictly speaking my code is non-portable. However, they happen to be true on the architectures and ABIs I'm currently targeting, and after careful consideration I've decided that the risk they will fail to hold on some architecture that I'll need to target in the future is acceptably low compared to the pragmatic benefits I derive from making the assumptions *now*.

The question is: how do I best document this decision? Many of my assumptions are made by practically everyone (non-octet `char`s? or sign-magnitude integers? on a future, commercially successful, architecture?). Others are more arguable -- the most risky probably being the one about function pointers. But if I just list *everything* I assume beyond what the standard gives me, the reader's eyes are just going to glaze over, and he may not notice the ones that actually matter.

So, is there some well-known set of assumptions about being a "somewhat orthodox" architecture that I can incorporate by reference, and then only document explicitly where I go beyond even that? (Effectively such a "profile" would define a new language that is a superset of C, but it might not acknowledge that in so many words -- and it may not be a pragmatically useful way to think of it either).

**Clarification**: I'm looking for a shorthand way to *document* my choices, not for a way to test automatically whether a given compiler matches my expectations. The latter is obviously useful too, but does not solve everything. For example, if a business partner contacts us saying, "we're making a device based on Google's new G2015 chip; will your software run on it?" -- then it would be nice to be able to answer "we haven't worked with that arch yet, but it shouldn't be a problem if it has a C compiler that satisfies such-and-such".

**Clarify even more** since somebody has voted to close as "not constructive": I'm not looking for discussion here, just for pointers to actual, existing, formal documents that can simplify my documentation by being incorporated by reference.

Comment: I think I'd describe it as a subset of C, not a superset. I'd see it as not "C and more", but "C and less". Effectively you'd be restricting what could be considered "C".

Comment: If you use autoconf you can document these with configure time tests.

Comment: @awoodland, both perspectives can be argued. I'm using "superset" in the sense of "more programs have a defined behavior". Of course that also means that "fewer compilers will meet these expectations".

Comment: One thing you could do is write a single feature test function that checks all those things, perhaps statically, and include that at some point early in your program.

Comment: Also: "pointer arithmetic on char* is the same as ordinary arithmetic on size_t" - isn't that already guaranteed as a hangover from K&R days?

Comment: "functions pointers can be cast to void* and back again without information loss." POSIX.1-2001 promises you that via `dlsym()`

Comment: @awoodland, thanks for POSIX. That's the kind of thing I'm looking for!

Comment: Not all of these are like the others.  I haven't touched a computer without 8-bit bytes and 2s-complement since 1989, and that Cyber was a fossil then.  That's almost certainly not only safe but expected.  "Integer division rounds negative quotients towards zero" is going to trip up quite a few people, although that's actually in the C99 and C++11 standards, and therefore future compilers should adhere to it.

Comment: @David Thornley, that is exactly my point (though I may have been inept in making it). I'm looking for a way to separate out the "almost certainly safe" assumptions from the ones that matter, with a more objective basis than my own experience about what _ought_ to be safe and expected. Though I do think highly of my own expertise, I'm categorically unqualified to judge whether it is sufficient ...

Comment: I think "comparisons involving NaN always evaluate to false." is the riskiest point up here; namely because that's not even true on most plain x86 compilers. (It's false on GCC without `-fsafe-math`, and it's false on MSVC++ without `/fp:strict`)

Comment: Scratch that -- at some point for GCC the default was changed to safe; you need `-funsafe-math` in order to get the potentially strange NaN behavior.

Comment: @Billy, the reason why I didn't nominate NaN as the riskiest was that it can be fixed by making the compiler stupider, so there's a fair chance that a compiler switch to do so will be provided. On the other hand, there's no easy way out if we meet an architecture where function pointers _must_ include a base register value in order to be ABI compatible.

Comment: Out of interest CSR's Bluecore chip has a 16-bit char, and that's certainly commercially successful (over 2 billion shipped).

Comment: @Henning: The problem with that assumption is that if you rely on specific compiler switches, you can induce dependency problems between (for example) your library and another vendor's library.

Comment: Some of your assumptions are likely unnecessary. *all data pointers have the same representation, and can be converted to `size_t` and back again without information loss` -- Replace `size_t` by `uintptr_t`. *a null pointer is all zero bits* -- It's usually not too difficult to write code that doesn't depend on that assumption; are you doing `memset` on structures?

Comment: POSIX guarantees that CHAR_BITS == 8

Comment: @Flexo: The more rigidly a language is specified, the more programmers will be able to do without relying upon unspecified behaviors.  The more loosely a language is specified, the less functionality can be safely used.  If imposing constraints on a language made it weaker, the ideal language should be QQ, where a compiler is allowed to interpret any sequence of characters as having any meaning whatsoever it sees fit.

Answer (score 6):

I would introduce a STATIC_ASSERT macro and put all your assumptions in such asserts.

Comment: I'm not too keen on relying entirely on experiment. For example, the main risk related to comparing to NaN is not that the implementation will _always_ get it wrong (relative to my expectations), but that it will _sometimes_ work and sometimes not, such as with a compiler that freely rewrites `a<b` to `!(a>=b)` and vice versa based on what it thinks will generate more efficient code in context. It is entirely plausible that a concrete experiment will succeed by accident, even if the compiler doesn't actually guarantee the behavior I rely on.

Comment: Fair point, your own application will always be the ultimate test. But I think this would be a good idea to establish at least some kind of base line guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, not only is there a lack of standards for a dialect of C that combines the extensions which have emerged as de facto standards during the 1990s (two's-complement, universally-ranked pointers, etc.) but compilers trends are moving in the opposite direction.  Given the following requirements for a function:

```
* Accept int parameters x,y,z:
* Return 0 if x-y is computable as "int" and is less than Z
* Return 1 if x-y is computable as "int" and is not less than Z
* Return 0 or 1 if x-y is not computable */
```

The vast majority of compilers in the 1990s would have allowed:

```
int diffCompare(int x, int y, int z)
{ return (x-y) >= z; }
```

On some platforms, in cases where the difference between x-y was not computable as `int`, it would be faster to compute a "wrapped" two's-complement value of `x-y` and compare that, while on others it would be faster to perform the calculation using a type larger than `int` and compare that.  By the late 1990s, however, nearly every C compiler would implement the above code to use one of whichever one of those approaches would have been more efficient on its hardware platform.

Since 2010, however, compiler writers seem to have taken the attitude that if computations overflow, compilers shouldn't perform the calculations in whatever fashion is normal for their platform and let what happens happens, nor should they recognizably trap (which would break some code, but could prevent certain kinds of errant program behavior), but instead they should overflows as an excuse to negate laws of time and causality.  Consequently, even if a programmer would have been perfectly happy with any behavior a 1990s compiler would have produced, the programmer must replace the code with something like:

```
{ return ((long)x-y) >= z; }
```

which would greatly reduce efficiency on many platforms, or

```
{ return x+(INT_MAX+1U)-y >= z+(INT_MAX+1U); }
```

which requires specifying a bunch of calculations the programmer doesn't actually want in the hopes that the optimizer will omit them (using signed comparison to make them unnecessary), and would reduce efficiency on a number of platforms (especially DSPs) where the form using `(long)` would have been more efficient.

It would be helpful if there were standard profiles which would allow programmers to avoid the need for nasty horrible kludges like the above using `INT_MAX+1U`, but if trends continue they will become more and more necessary.

Comment: If `int` overflow was implementation-defined behavior rather than undefined behavior, would this solve the this issue?

Comment: @chux: If an action invokes Implementation-Defined Behavior, implementations are *required* to specify the precise effect; if an action may trigger behaviors outside the control of the C compiler, it *can't* invoke Implementation-Defined Behavior.  The problem is that at present the only category of behavior such actions can trigger is Undefined Behavior, even if 99.99% of implementations would have no difficulty categorizing the behavior as an arbitrary choice among a small number of alternatives.

Comment: @chux: IMHO, the best way to solve the problem would be by replacing most forms of Undefined Behavior with what I would term Testably-Constrained Behaviors; I would further replace most forms of Implementation-Defined Behavior with Testably-Specified Behavior.  In either case, standardized means would exist by which a program could say e.g. "I need type coercions from `uint16_t` to `int16_t` to yield the value which is congruent to the original mod 65536" [such behavior is presently IB] or "I need `x<<32` to yield either `x` or 0--I don't care which" [presently UB].

Comment: A reasonable proposition you have, still allowing for some variant behavior.  Akin to `int` _must_ be 1 of 3 forms.

Comment: @chux: I'd go beyond allowing "some" variant behavior.  Implementations with reasons for doing something outside the jurisdiction of the Standard would be free to specify that certain things invoke Undefined Behavior and free themselves from any constraint *beyond the requirement to specify that their behavior is not anticipated by the Standard*.  Code written for such platforms would be free to make use of their behaviors, while code which can't deal with such behaviors could refuse compilation.

Comment: @chux: I'm not sure how politically possible it would be to declare certain things as "normative" or "non-normative", but if a lot of program is written which specifies that certain actions must yield certain behavior and not others, that would give compiler writers an incentive to support such guarantees in the absence of good reasons not to.

Answer (score 0):

Most compiler documentation includes a section that describes the specific behavior of implementation-dependent features.    Can you point to that section of the gcc or msvc docs to describe your assumptions?

Comment: I could, but that would amount to s much stronger requirement than I want to make. It's not going to impress customers much if I tell them that "my code is fairly portable: it will work on any compiler that does things exactly the same ways as GCC on x86".

Answer (score 0):

You can write a header file `"document.h"` where you collect all your assumptions.
Then, in every file that you know that non-standard assumptions are made, you can `#include` such a file.
Perhaps `"document.h"` would not have real sentences at all, but only commented text and some macros.

```
   // [T] DOCUMENT.H
   //

   #ifndef DOCUMENT_H
   #define DOCUMENT_H 
   // [S] 1. Basic assumptions.
   // 
   // If this file is included in a compilation unit it means that
   // the following assumptions are made:
   //      [1] A char has 8 bits.
   // [#]

   #define MY_CHARBITSIZE 8

   //      [2] IEEE 754 doubles are addopted for type: double.
   // ........
   // [S] 2. Detailed information
   //
   #endif
```

The tags in brackets: `[T] [S] [#] [1] [2]` stand for:

```
* [T]: Document Title
* [S]: Section
* [#]: Print the following (non-commented) lines as a code-block.
* [1], [2]: Numbered items of a list.
```

Now, the idea here is to use the file "document.h" in a different way:

- To parse the file in order to convert the comments in "document.h" to some printable document, or some basic HTML.

Thus, the tags [T] [S] [#] etc., are intended to be interpreted by a parser that convert any comment into an HTML line of text (for example), and generate `<h1></h1>, <b></b>` (or whatever you want), when a tag appears.

If you keep the parser as a simple and small program, this can give you a short hand to handle this kind of documentation.